# Gammu on my Raspberry Pi (2 and 3) works perfectly only for 30 minutes

Tags: python, sms, gammu, interruption

I meanwhile installed gammu in two different raspberry pi (2 and 3), and it works fine - but only for rather exactly 30 minutes. The daemon (according to top) continues, but no sms is sent or received. A shutdown -r command or a reboot allows to exchange sms - but again only for 30 minutes. I am using a Huawei USB dongle. The whole thing works fine when I ask the Raspi by a cron-job to restart every 30 minutes, but I'm losing then all data of my Python program...

I did a search for many days in Internet. There was the same question asked by someone else in forum-rapsberry.de. Unfortunately unanswered. I kindly ask for help here.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed this problem.
Have had this issue as well. But then I worked on some software for the rasp using another serial port for communications with some atmel chips and I figured out that the problem on the rasp is the speed you setup for the serial communication. Sometimes it works and then it just doesn‘t. :p
Well the rasp is cheap and tiny and bits become more unstable the faster your serial data is sent. So simply reduce the speed on the serial port to something lower such as 14400!
The default value („connection=at“) is so so so much to fast (115200 bits per second).

Edit gammu-smsd in /etc and replace „connection = at“ with „connection = at14400“.

```
/etc/gammu-smsd

# Configuration file for Gammu SMS Daemon
# Gammu library configuration, see gammurc(5)
[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB1
name = Phone on USB serial port USB_Modem USB_Modem
connection = at14400
(…)
```

Enjoy.

PS: Also ensure your power supply is sufficient:  [Link](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply)